# Receiving Broadcast Sent From Library Module in App Module

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-library, android-broadcast

I am having problem receiving broadcast sent from android library module in app module.

I create an explicit broadcast with action and component name. And send this broadcast from android lib module.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = "com.example.action.SOME_ACTION"
intent.component = ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyReceiver")
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

To receive this broadcast, I created a receiver and registered it in manifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.action.SOME_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This receiver prints received event, but unfortunately, I am not receiving any broadcast. Am I missing anything? Or is it supposed to be this way, i.e. You cannot receive broadcast sent from the library?

Comment: use `EventBus` to receive broadcast from a different module https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I don't wanna depend on any library.

Answer (score 1):

try to do like this, this is working for me

register receiver where you want to receive using this code

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("myCustomAction");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

send a broadcast from different lib like this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("myCustomAction");
    intent.putExtra("value", 0);
    intent.setComponent(null);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

now no need to register a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

set `ComponentName` to null because `ComponentName` is

> The name of the application component to handle the
>        intent, or null to let the system find one for you.

Comment: But this will not work when app is terminated or when component, where receiver is registered, is terminated.